# selecting only child elements inside parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to use the [jQuery Equal Heights Plugin by Raja Sekharan](http://bit.ly/1q38jn) to equal the column heights on two different rows. I've tried several ways to select JUST the contained columns but every time the biggest height is used across both rows.

Best way of explaining this is with [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/REzGg/1/)

How do I get the top row to inherit the largest size from that `section` only and the bottom row to inherit the largest size from it's `section`?

Note: I can't use IDs on the sections. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your selector is just passing all of the cols into the function regardless of where they are.

You could try something like:

```
$('.col-base').each(function() {
    setEqualHeight($(this).children('.col'));
});
```